# jsTree 3.0.2 - How to pass parameter to aspx webmethod

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, jstree

I'm trying to pass a parameter from jsTree 3.0.2 to a web method on an aspx page but it is not hitting the web method.  It does however work when there are no parameters.  Can anyone point out the error of my ways?

**With parameter (not working):**

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public static IEnumerable<JsTreeNode> GetAll(string id)
{
    // method does not get called
}

$("#jsTreeTest").jstree({
    "core": {
        "data": {
            "url": "MyPage.aspx/GetAll",
            "type": 'POST',
            "dataType": 'JSON',
            "contentType": 'application/json;',
            'data': function (node) {
                return { 'id': "01" };
            }
        }
    }
});
```

**Without parameter (Working):**

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public static IEnumerable<JsTreeNode> GetAll()
{
    // successfully calls method
}

$("#jsTreeTest").jstree({
    "core": {
        "data": {
            "url": "MyPage.aspx/GetAll",
            "type": 'POST',
            "dataType": 'JSON',
            "contentType": 'application/json;',
            "data": function (node) { return {}; }
        }
    }
});
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Found the problem.  It should be:

```
return '{ "id" : "01" }';
```

**Working Code:**

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public static IEnumerable<JsTreeNode> GetAll(string id)
{
    // success!
}

$("#jsTreeTest").jstree({
    "core": {
        "data": {
            "url": "MyPage.aspx/GetAll",
            "type": 'POST',
            "dataType": 'JSON',
            "contentType": 'application/json;',
            "data": function (node) {
                return '{ "id" : "01" }';
            }
        }
    }
});
```